# Vacuum-packed (or not?) bacon, safe to use?

Tags: bacon, vacuum

I purchased a 3-pack of bacon a week ago, basically 3 vacuum packed (is that the right word for this?) bacon, stripped together (probably made together, seems like the plastic was just sealed between three clusters of bacon.)

I have discovered that one of the packages is not void of air, but it is apparently airtight, I can squeeze on the package and it doesn't give in or seem to vent any air, it just contains air, whereas the other package (I have already used one) is void of air, which is what I expected it to be.

So my question is, is the package that contains air safe to use?

The expiration date on the packages are middle of next month, so they're well within their intended usage, but I'm just not sure about the air.

Does anyone know?

Considering they were cheap packages, I will probably just toss it, but since I planned on using the packages for dinner today, I probably need to come up with a backup plan, unless, of course, it is entirely safe to eat.

So what's the verdict?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The existence of gas in a vacuum-sealed environment could be a sign of microbial activity.  I would assume that, since the package appears to be sealed, that the gases in it were introduced from within.  I would toss that one and feel OK using the other two.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a plan then.

Answer (score 4):

Give it a sniff.  If it smells ok then it probably is.

I've stopped looking at sell by dates/ use by dates etc and have started using my nose.

Supermarket bacon in this country is sold in plastic boxes which contain air.  They usually last approx 1 week once opened.

I buy my bacon from my butcher and it is just put in a plastic bag.  Not had a problem so far.

Comment: I came up with an alternate plan, I just take off the package that seems OK, and take the other one back to the store, I probably stop by there tomorrow. With any luck, they'll give me a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I just called Farmer JOhn regarding the same situation.   The consumer rep advised me to toss the bacon because it must have been compromised.   She said that it would not be safe to eat and offered a coupon to replace another package.    She advised that microbacteria could be in the product and I should not cook and eat it!

Answer (score -2):

Bacon keeps for weeks even if not sealed as long as it is kept refrigerated. It contains salt which preserves it.

Comment: You're assuming that it wasn't sealed.  If it *was* sealed properly, and has now filled up with air, that's a sign that something is horribly, horribly wrong.